# Connection error with heroku db:push with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, taps

I have suddenly started seeing this strange error when trying to push my database to heroku.

```
> heroku db:push
Auto-detected local database: postgres://infinity:infinity@localhost/infinity_development?encoding=utf8
Failed to connect to database:
Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> TypeError wrong argument type String (expected Array)
```

My app works fine - the credentials are all set locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm ... once again this all just started magically working.